# Textbrowser displaying an image showing "QFSEngine::open: No file specified " warning

Tags: html, qt, qtextbrowser

I´m using a QTextBrowser to display an external html document (and its image resources) which is placed in the same directory as the application.The relative paths don't work at all and If I type in the absolute file path of the image, it is displayed fine but a warning appears before the html document is loaded. The warning says "QFSEngine::open: No file specified" . i'm loading my html file using this snippet :

```
QFile file(QApplication::applicationDirPath().append("/test.html"));
if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite|QIODevice::Text))
return;
QTextStream in(&file);
ui->textBrowser->setHtml(in.readAll());
file.close();
```

and this is my html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<img src="test.png">
<p>paragraph which contains some text</p>
</html>
```

Am i going wrong in reading the html or is there anything i have to include in my cpp file?

Comment: `Application dir` != `Current dir`. Especially under debug. Try to call `setCurrentDir( "path_to_html" )` before opening it.

Comment: I have now set my path for Qfile as QFile file("path_to_html"); but i still see no change in the behaviour .

Comment: I didn't talk about QFile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call [`QTextBrowser::setSearchPaths`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextbrowser.html#searchPaths-prop) with full path to your .html.